# Eigen trivially_copyable and CUDA

Tags: c++, eigen, thrust

I have a struct which contains some Eigen::Vector3d values. I have a vector of that struct and I want to upload it to the GPU using thrust.

When I did that, I got an error saying that the copy was undefined. I've been trying to understand why it can't use default cudaMemcpy and it looks like Eigen::Vector3d is not trivially_copyable.

I'm trying to understand why its not, but I cant find any reason. AFAIK, Eigen::Vector3d is just 3 continuous double values. Why is that not trivially_copyable? What are the possible errors I can find if I cudaMemcpy that vector by hand  directly?

Edit: The question has been marked as a duplicate of [thrust device to host undefined cross_system_copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217788/thrust-device-to-host-undefined-cross-system-copy). I don't think its an exact duplicate, although its related. In that question I'm asking if I should do something special to make thrust work with Eigen. In this question I'm asking why a Eigen::Vector3d is not trivially_copyable and asking what can happen if I decide to cudaMemcpy by hand the content of a std::vector. I think they are different enough questions so I decided to ask it as a separate question.

Comment: It should be trivially copyable, since it only contains trivial types. But there is a copy-constructor implemented (which would be `= default`, if that was possible with C++03), which is required for some internal technicalities, I think.
You can try to remove the copy constructor from `Matrix` (and maybe from all base classes as well) and see if everything still works.

Comment: "A trivially copyable class is a class that: has no non-trivial copy constructors, has no non-trivial move constructors, has no non-trivial copy assignment operators, has no non-trivial move assignment operators, and has a trivial destructor."

Comment: @talonmies I know I should have been a bit more precise with my wording. What I intended to say was that "nothing should go wrong if you `std::memcpy` an `Eigen::Vector3d`". That is of course not equivalent to "trivially copyable" in the C++-sense.

Comment: You can't be certain that alignment of host and device structures (especially those over which you have no control of) will be identical . So a byte copy won't be guaranteed to work

Comment: In that case, what would be the correct way of sending this to cuda?